# How to detect if a div is out of page boundaries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some jQuery to show a div pop up when you hover over a link. But the problem happens when the link is too close to the right side of the browser window and the content of the popup isn't visible.

I have made an example with the identical jQuery code here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GggLrw

I believe one `if` statement can solve the problem, some pseudo code:

```
if(element is out of boundaries){
    moveleft=-400;
}
```

I only need to move the div to the left, going out of boundaries to the bottom wont be a problem, links with hover trigger won't be so low n the page

Comment: You should include your code in the question as links rot and users shouldnt have to go to external sites. Remove what you dont need to minimalize code if it is too big to post here.

Comment: Ok, will remember that for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this JS code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;

  jQuery('.box').hover(function(e) {

   if (e.pageX+jQuery('div.hidden').width() > jQuery(document).width()) {
      moveLeft = -20 - jQuery('div.hidden').width();
   }
   else
   {
       moveLeft = 20;
   }

    jQuery('div.hidden').show();
  }, function() {
    jQuery('div.hidden').hide();
  });

  jQuery('.box').mousemove(function(e) {
    jQuery("div.hidden").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
  });

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJJQRM

Comment: moveLeft is a variable which by deafault moves the hovering div from the mouse to the left side, in this case it has been given a negative value resulting the div to move to the right

Answer (score 0):

You check the position of the tool tip, add it's dimensions, and compare that to the size of the viewport which is in this case window.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myygmQ

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;

  jQuery('.box').hover(function(e) {
    jQuery('div.hidden').show();
  }, function() {
    jQuery('div.hidden').hide();
  });

  jQuery('.box').mousemove(function(e) {
    var newY = e.pageY + moveDown;
    var newX = e.pageX + moveLeft;
    var yOver = (newY + $('.hidden').height()) - $(window).height();
    var xOver = (newX + $('.hidden').width()) - $(window).width();
    if(yOver > 0) newY -= yOver;
    if(xOver > 0) newX -= xOver;
    jQuery("div.hidden").css({top: newY, left: newX});
  });

});
```

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:gray;
}

.mid{
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.right{
  float: right;
}

.box.hidden{
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box left">
  <p>I am a regular box with a <a href="javascript:;">link</a></p>
</div>

<div class="box mid">
  <p>I am a regular box with a <a href="javascript:;">link</a></p>
</div>

<div class="box right">
  <p>I am a regular box with a <a href="javascript:;">link</a></p>
</div>

<div class="box hidden">
  <p>I am a hidden box with some content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, laudantium accusamus magnam id molestias tempore excepturi molestiae repellat voluptatum sunt aspernatur ab, voluptates officiis rerum amet similique, libero ea a.</p>
</div>
```